# Train/validate/test subsets of the data; which one do we use?

Tags: machine-learning, reporting, train-test-split

We are writing a scientific paper using a large dataset of healthcare data. We split our data into three sets: a train set (60%), a validation set (20%), and a test set (20%).

My question is what do we use for each section of the paper. The estimation procedure is run on the train set. This is for sure.

- What do we use for the descriptive table?
- Would the testing of the model-fit be the test set? And the simulation using our estimation be the validation set?